# Guava Joiner throws NPE on null elements

Tags: java, guava

Is the initialization of `Joiner` incorrect here? I have the following class, and when I try to join the example `paths` array with the `joiner`, I am getting a `NullPointerException`.

```
public class CPath {
  private static final Joiner joiner = Joiner.on("/");

  private String[] elements;

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return joiner.join(elements);
  }
}

// main method
final String[] paths = {"a/b/c", "d", "", null, "e/f/g", "h/i", null, ""};
final CPath c3 = new CPath(paths);
c3.toString(); //<<<< NPE
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use either `skipNulls()`, or `useForNull(defaultValue)`, it is on the top of its documentation;

> If neither skipNulls() nor useForNull(String) is specified, the joining methods will throw NullPointerException if any given element is null.

So you have to initialize `joiner` like;

```
Joiner joiner = Joiner.on("/").skipNulls();
```

or

```
Joiner joiner = Joiner.on("/").useForNull("");
```

[Documentation of Joiner from Guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/16.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html)